# Meteor Blaze tab key event

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

This Meteor code does not print to console the `event.which` so as to use tab key event when tabbing out of an editable div.
Why editable div? Because I can style part of the string which is not allowed in input element.

BTW: Where do I find a list of the events types for Meteor Blaze. There site only lists a very limited events. [Other DOM events are available as well, but...](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Event-Maps)

I tried some [blur and onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element#focus_events) for no avail.
How can I fire a tab key event on an editable div? Thanks

```js
//client/main.js template evnet

  'onblur #vin'(e){
    console.log(e.which)  //prints nothing
    let vin = e.target.value

  }
```

```html
    <div class="body">
      <div id="vin" class="editable" contenteditable="true">{{vehicle.vin_a}}<span id="vinb">{{vehicle.vin_b}}</span><span id="vin4">{{vehicle.vin4}}</span></div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="make, modle, date">
    </div>
```

Comment: typo `onblue` -> `onblur`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me!

Here is a minimal, reproducible example:

main.html:

```js
<head>
  <title>b</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> info}}
</body>

<template name="info">
  <div id="vin" class="editable" contenteditable="true">
    Edit me
  </div>
</template>
```

main.js:

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './main.html';

Template.info.events({
  'blur #vin'(event, instance) {
    console.log('blur!', event);
  }
});
```

Maybe you defined the event on the wrong template?